# What does unhandled CFI instruction 0:50 mean?

Tags: valgrind

I am using valgrind to debug a c++ program.  At the beginning it says:

DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:50

I have googled this, but have been unable to find an explanation as to what this means.  Thanks in advance.